# A metal can rolling down an incline

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I need help with this question:

A metal can containing condensed mushroom soup has mass 215g,height 10.8cm, and a diameter of 6.38cm. It is placed at reston its side at the top of a 3.00m-long incline plane that is at25.0o to the horizontal and is then released to rollstraight down. It reaches the bottom of the incline after1.50s. Assuming mechanical energy conservation, calculate themoment of inertia of the can. Which pieces of data, if any,are unnecessary for calculating the solution.

So here is the problem I am having. I will explain my thought process below. Please tell me where I go wrong!

I started to use the conservation of energy equation for this problem while noticing that there is both rotational and translational kinetic energy with potential energy. Once I have the equation set up, I am left with the unknown of the final velocity of the center of mass. Since the length of the incline is 3, and the angle from the horizontal is 25, then the vertical height is 3*sin25. Then, using the kinematics of a particle, I need to find the final velocity by using vf=vi+at. Since a is unknown as well, I will then use yf=yi+vit+1/2at^2. However, by using those kinematic equations, I do not get the right velocity. Please help, this is extremely frustrating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a distance, a time, and an expected constant acceleration.  That should be sufficient for you to calculate a final linear velocity.

> Since $a$ is unknown as well, I will then use $y_f=y_i+v_it+1/2at^2$

While that equation is possible, it looks like you might be equating the first $a$ with the second.  In the equation, you could rearrange to calculate an effective vertical acceleration ($a_y$), which would be different from the linear acceleration along the ramp.